# Swift 5: Add UITableView with dynamic prototype cells in XIB

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to add a UITableView element to a XIB which I want to present as a sheet from the bottom but I only get the option of static cells. Isn't it possible to have dynamic tables within a XIB or am I missing something?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tTkl.png]

Usually Content Field is visible and I select 1 prototype cell for simple use cases

[image]

Comment: Can you explain more about your problem? xib can handle all things you want, that works like a storyboard.

Comment: @MaziarSaadatfar : sorry if I am not being clear enough, when I create a simple table I usually just select the Content as Dynamic Prototypes and the select 1 Prototype Cell which I customise with simple info in cellForRowAt function. But since the "Content" field is not visible in XIB when I add a Table View element, how can I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A prototype cell is a feature of a table view *controller*, not a table view. You would need to have a table view controller object in your XIB in order to have a prototype cell. Having a table view controller in a XIB is a perfectly legal thing to do, though it is rarely done nowadays, because storyboards are generally easier to work with and are more powerful.

I don't recommend putting a table view controller in a XIB just in order to get a prototype cell. Keep in mind that there are also two other ways of having the runtime instantiate a cell for you when you dequeue:

- Register a XIB file that contains just a cell object.
- Or, register a cell type that is a UITableViewCell subclass.

Or just use a storyboard if you really want a prototype cell. A storyboard containing nothing but a single table view controller scene is perfectly legal and viable.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried adding the Table View Controller into the XIB but it didn't work, Xcode doesn't allow me to do that

Comment: Oh yes, it does. I tried it just to be sure, before answering. But, as I said, I don't advise it in any case now that storyboards exist.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to achieve my goal using matt's answer via creating a Storyboard and assign it to my custom UIViewController class.

[image]

Make sure to set the Class and Storyboard ID:

[image]

The code to present and use the Storyboard from the the presenting ViewController:

```
let popup = UIStoryboard(name: "MyPopupVC", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "myPopupUniqueID") as! MyPopupVC

if let sheet = popup.sheetPresentationController {
sheet.detents = [.large()]
sheet.prefersGrabberVisible = true
}
popup.set(account: account) //Transfer account object to popup VC
present(popup, animated: true)
```